# Query return empty result but data exist

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, slim

I'm using `Slim` with `PDO` with `MySql` for return a specific list of `matches` available in my database. My query is this:

```
SELECT m.*, 
       t.name AS home_team_name, 
       t2.name AS away_team_name 
FROM `match` m 
LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
WHERE (home_team_id = 117 OR away_team_id = 117) AND round_id = 488
```

if I execute this `query` I'll get a list of `matches`:

[image]

but inside the `API` developed with `Slim` I get an empty array. This is the method structure:

```
$app->get('/match/get_matches_by_team/{round_id}/{team_id}/{type}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $query = "SELECT m.*,
  t.name AS home_team_name,
  t2.name AS away_team_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  WHERE ";

  switch($args["type"])
  {
    case "home":
          $query .= "home_team_id = :team_id AND ";
    break;
    case "away":
        $query .= "away_team_id = :team_id AND ";
    break;
    default:
        $query .= "(home_team_id = :team_id OR away_team_id = :team_id) AND ";
    break;
  }

  $query .= "round_id = :round_id";

  $sql = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $sql->bindParam("team_id", $args["team_id"]);
  $sql->bindParam("round_id", $args["round_id"]);
  $sql->execute();

  $result = $sql->fetchAll();
  return $response->withJson($result);
});
```

what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

If I do `echo $query; return;` I'll get:

```
SELECT m.*,
t.name AS home_team_name,
  t2.name AS away_team_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  WHERE away_team_id = :team_id AND round_id = :round_id
```

supposing to pass `away`, if instead I pass `all` I'll get:

```
SELECT m.*,
t.name AS home_team_name,
  t2.name AS away_team_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  WHERE (home_team_id = :team_id OR away_team_id = :team_id) AND round_id = :round_id
```

**UPDATE 2**

Method updated with proposed hints

```
$app->get('/match/get_matches_by_team
/{round_id}/{team_id}/{type}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $query = "SELECT m.*,
  t.name AS home_team_name,
  t2.name AS away_team_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  WHERE ";

switch($args["type"])
   {
    case "home":
          $query .= "home_team_id = :home_team_id 
    AND ";
        break;
        case "away":
            $query .= "away_team_id = :away_team_id AND ";
        break;
        default:
            $query .= "(home_team_id = :home_team_id OR away_team_id = :away_team_id) AND ";
        break;
      }

      $query .= "round_id = :round_id";

      $sql = $this->db->prepare($query);
      $sql->bindParam("home_team_id", $args["team_id"]);
      $sql->bindParam("away_team_id", $args["team_id"]);
      $sql->bindParam("round_id", $args["round_id"]);
      $sql->execute();

      $result = $sql->fetchAll();
      return $response->withJson($result);
    });
```

Comment: Print the query out that you are executing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check my update

Comment: . . Can you get *any* query with a named parameter to work?  I mean, just do `select :param` and see if the value is returned as you expect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if I do just `SELECT * FROM :param` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yours:

```
 $sql->bindParam("team_id", $args["team_id"]);
 $sql->bindParam("round_id", $args["round_id"]);
```

try this, the params might be needed to be formatted differently

```
$sql->bindParam(":team_id", $args["team_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(":round_id", $args["round_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or

```
$sql->bindParam(":team_id", $args["team_id"]);
$sql->bindParam(":round_id", $args["round_id"]);
```

Comment: @popop hmm okay lemme look again

Answer (score 1):

When the default switch is selected, you are trying to bind a value with the same parameter marker (in your case :team_id) twice. In order for this to work you have to turn on emulation mode in PDO.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Comment: What you did will now throw an error in the other 2 cases because the binded values are not the same as your parameter markers. You either have to turn on emulation mode with your previous approach or run the same switch and only bind the corresponding variables. Also you have to add `:` in your `bindParam` calls

Comment: i don't see any PDO error reporting mechanism in your code :)

Comment: I declared the error reporting in slim configuration and so far worked as expected, anyway, thanks for the help